# WPF:SelectedItem Property updating to null is not working through DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two lists and trying to clear selection of one list when we select item in another list.

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem1,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=listBox2, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ConverterValuer},ConverterParameter=list1}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Name="listBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyData2}" SelectionChanged="listBox2_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ConverterValuer},ConverterParameter=list2}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}"/>

                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

I have used converter to check selectedItem is null or not as below

```
 public class ConverterParameter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
             bool result = value == null;
            return result;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

To extend whether datatrigger is becoming true or not I tried to change the background color and it is working only SelectedItem is not setting to null.

why I am not able to understand.

Let me help to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Nagasree.

Comment: 1. How do you instantiate the ConverterParameter (IValueConverter)? 2. I would avoid naming the class ConverterParameter because it is not a Parameter but a ValueConverter. 3. In your xaml, it is not necessary to pass ConverterParameter (real parameter, because you do not use it in the ValueConverter. 4. You have circular SelectedItem setter for the 2 listboxes, that will cause each SelectedItem to be deselected once selected.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in XAML. Even if you aren't doing pure MVVM, your view layer should be responding to events in your view logic layer, not generating them itself.

Comment: @kurakura88 I have to deselect item in one list if I select in another list and viceversa.